# Create a new app or improved the existing one

Tags: android, android-studio, optimization

I created an app one year ago (2000 download, 350 active users) and I have to clean the code, use Material Design...and I don't know what is the best solution. Make it from scratch (so create a new app) and give to the old user the possibility to **import their old dat**a into the new app or improve the existing one ?

Comment: It depends. Try going through your code once. If the core functionality is complex, you can understand it, and still remember everything(documentation, if any, would help here), then you can probably improve the existing one. If the core functionality is easy to implement, then you should probably make it from scratch. You are the best judge for that.

Comment: You can create a new one but as update from the existing app. To achieve this, you should retain the package name, the keystore file of the app and increment its version code (from exising version) before uploading to playstore as an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need not to make it from scratch because major change will be in UI side. this will be more easy task than other one.

while on other side making it from scratch and give to the old user the possibility to import their old data into the new app will be difficult as you have to do it from begging and have to maintaining data.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your answers. I will try to update the existing one (UI + clean code) !

Answer (score 1):

You can make an update for improving the UX/UI and upload in playstore. Users can resume the status by updating the old app. You can also make it from scratch but keep the keystore same and build version up-to-date.